# React native, import and read local xml file

Tags: xml, react-native, getfiles

I'm new to React Native framework. I'm trying to use it for make a cross-platform mobile app.
I want to open and read a local XML file, present in my app folder, but I can't work out how to do this.

My biggest problem at the moment is how to assign this local XML file to a variable, I've tried with the `require` command, or with `import`, but these commands haven't worked.

Comment: Having the same issue, @Nicolo did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your xml file to a javascript object, so that you can work with it. Maybe you could use [react-native-xml2js](https://github.com/connected-lab/react-native-xml2js)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but for now I don't jet resolve my problem. I'm trying this code :
    var RNFS = require('react-native-fs'), 
    xml2js = require('react-native-xml2js'); 
    RNFS.readFile(..... 

My problem is that I'm not able to pass the path of my project directory where are saved the xml that I would parse

Comment: @NicolòMazzoli did you manage to fix this issue, if so please post your solution..